# Syncronous execution and setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

My goal is to get the following output:

1, 2 (*wait 2s*) 3, 4 (*wait 2s*) 5 but instead I get 1, 2, 4 (wait 2s) 3, 5.

**Does anyone know how to fix this problem?**

```js
console.log("1");
console.log("2");
setTimeout(function(){console.log("3")}, 2000);
console.log("4");
setTimeout(function(){console.log("5")}, 2000);
```

Comment: Could you use Promises instead? It'll make the logic easier to understand

Comment: To add, I would also say use `async / await` it would make even easier to understand..

Comment: @Keith, Its my first time using hearing about promises. I don't know how to use them in this scenario. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `setTimeout` is asynchronous. JS go to the first line, print 1, then second line, print 2, then third line - it's async, so it will be executed later (in 2000ms as you put), then forth line, print 4, and fifth line, execute in 2000ms (as the third). So you get 1, 2 and 4 instantly, then 2000ms after 3 and 5. To get what you want, see the code below:

```js
console.log("1")
console.log("2")

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("3")
  console.log("4")
}, 2000)

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("5")
}, 4000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of using `async / await`..

```js
function sleep(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); }

async function test() {
  console.log("1");
  console.log("2");
  await sleep(2000);
  console.log("3");
  console.log("4");
  await sleep(2000);
  console.log("5");
}

test();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand [how JavaScript runs the code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop):

When you call the code, it runs to completion, which means the code is executed all at once. What set timeout does is pushes the inner function to event loop to be executed later. Let me comment what happens, please remember stack's execution model is last in first out. Functions will be popped off the stack when they execute return:

```js
// a log function is pushed to stack and popped
console.log("1");

// another log function is pushed to stack and popped
console.log("2");

// setTimeout is pushed to stack and popped
// When popped it added an anonymous function to the event loop
setTimeout(function(){console.log("3")}, 2000);

// another log function is pushed to stack
console.log("4");

// settimeout is pushed to stack and popped

// When popped it added an anonymous function to the event loop
setTimeout(function(){console.log("5")}, 2000);
```

When there is no more function to push on to stack, JavaScript engines starts to execute the event loop. So inner functions of setTimeous are waiting to be pushed onto stack. When the time outs, they will be pushed to stack.

So you need to change your code as follows:

```js
// a log function is pushed to stack and popped
console.log("1");

// another log function is pushed to stack and popped
console.log("2");

// first settimeout is pushed to stack
// When executed inner function will be added to event loop because of setTimeout
// In 2000 miliseconds, the event loop will push this function to the stack
setTimeout(function(){
  // When executed
  // another log function will be pushed to stack and popped
  console.log("3")
  
  // another log function will be pushed to stack and popped
  console.log("4");
  
  // second setTimeout is pushed to stack, which in turn pushes inner anonymous function to event loop
  setTimeout(function(){

    // another log function will be pushed to stack and popped
    console.log("5");
      
    // After this point second setTimeout and first setTimeout will be popped in order
      
  }, 2000);
  
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("1");
console.log("2");
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("3");
  console.log("4");
  }, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){console.log("5")}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best explanation for async/await

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function